# [Qt Quick]C++側でQ_PROPERTYの値を更新しても画面に反映されない

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Qt初心者です。
初学のために、Buttonを押したらTextFieldの値をLabelに表示するというアプリを作ろうとしています。
作成中のソースコードはこちらにあります。

[実際のソースコード](https://github.com/neko3cs/neko3cs-lab/tree/039d26214273838d054a24904422e756d581d2a7/sample/qt-quick-sample-app)

実現したいことは、C++側でLabelの値をTextFieldで更新し、表示を変えることです。
TextFieldに設定しているQ_PROPERTYのメンバ変数をLabelのメンバ変数に代入してみましたが、NULLか空文字になってしまい、Labelの表示も空になってしまいます。

どうしたら、C++側だけで値のLabelの表示を更新出来るか教えていただきたいです。
出来るだけ表示と処理は分離したく、かつ、QML側に一々idを振りたくないです。

ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

なお、以下の方法では更新出来ることは確認しています。

#### QML

```
// 中略
TextField {
  id: textField
  width: 200
  text: mainWindow.textFieldText
  placeholderText: "Type something..."
}

Button {
  text: "Update Label"
  onClicked: mainWindow.updateLabel(textField);
}
// 中略
```

#### C++

```cpp
// 中略
void MainWindow::updateLabel(const QString &text)
{
  m_labelText = text;
  emit labelTextChanged();
}
// 中略
```

Answer (score 0):

サンプルコードを確認しました。

QML の中から、C++ 側で作成した QObject のサブクラスのインスタンスにアクセスするために必要な処理が抜けていると思います。

main.cpp の中で、MainWindow.qml をロードする前に、以下のメソッドを実行してみてください。
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlapplicationengine.html#setInitialProperties

詳細は以下のドキュメントを参照してみてください。
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-methods-including-qt-slots

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。記事確認しました。やりたいこととちょっとイメージが違うかもです。そもそもC++側で `m_textFieldText` を持てるので、その値を使いたいです。 tasuku さんのイメージに合ってるかわからないですが、頂いた記事を参考に [修正してみましたが](https://github.com/neko3cs/neko3cs-lab/tree/fix/qt-quick-sample-app/q-property-update/sample/qt-quick-sample-app/src) 動作としては `m_textFieldText` をC++側で直接代入した時と同じ挙動でした。